Why does an error occur when using proj4 and proj4Leaflet?
I get an error when applying the coordinate system data
Error: Invalid LatLng object: (NaN, NaN)
    at new D (leaflet.js:5:6566)
    at i.unproject (proj4leaflet.js:46:11)
    at i.pointToLatLng (leaflet.js:5:11723)
    at i.unproject (leaflet.js:5:36364)
    at i.layerPointToLatLng (leaflet.js:5:36468)
    at i.getCenter (leaflet.js:5:34446)
    at i._update (leaflet.js:5:107645)
    at i.redraw (leaflet.js:5:102125)
    at i.setParams (leaflet.js:5:114368)
    at WMS_REDRAW (const.js:42:39)

EPSG data:
"EPSG:4216": {
      "data_code": "EPSG:4216",
      "name": "Bermuda 1957",
      "proj4": "+proj=longlat +ellps=clrk66 +towgs84=-292.295,248.758,429.447,-4.9971,-2.99,-6.6906,1.0289 +no_defs +type=crs",
      "center": [-64.75, 32.32],
      "bounds": [[-64.89, 32.21], [-64.61, 32.43]]
    }

My code:
async function applyCrsToMap(data) {
    let newCrs, worldCopyJump;

    if (data.data_code === "EPSG:3857") {

        worldCopyJump = true;
        map.options.crs = L.CRS.EPSG3857;
        map.setMaxBounds(null);
    } else {
        map.options.crs = L.CRS.EPSG3857;
        proj4.defs(data.data_code, data.proj4);
        newCrs = new L.Proj.CRS(data.data_code, proj4.defs(data.data_code), {
            origin: [0, 0],
            resolutions: [
                16384, 8192, 4096, 2048, 1024, 512, 256, 128, 64, 32, 16
            ],
            bounds: L.bounds(data.bounds[0], data.bounds[1])
        });

        worldCopyJump = false;

        let center4326 = proj4(data.proj4, 'EPSG:4326', data.center);
        let bounds4326 = [
            proj4(data.proj4, 'EPSG:4326', data.bounds[0]),
            proj4(data.proj4, 'EPSG:4326', data.bounds[1])
        ];
        
        let latLngBounds4326 = L.latLngBounds(
            [bounds4326[0][1], bounds4326[0][0]], 
            [bounds4326[1][1], bounds4326[1][0]]
        );

        let extendedBounds = latLngBounds4326.pad(0.2);
        map.options.crs = newCrs;

        map.setMaxBounds(extendedBounds);
        map.setView([center4326[1], center4326[0]], 4);
    }

    map.dragging.disable();
    delete map.dragging._draggable;
    map.options.worldCopyJump = worldCopyJump;
    map.dragging.enable();

    map.invalidateSize();

    map.eachLayer(function(layer) {
        map.removeLayer(layer);
        map.addLayer(layer);
    });
}

I'm using leaflet. Why does this error occur?
I get the coordinate system data here - https://epsg.io/4216
proj4.defs("EPSG:4219","+proj=longlat +ellps=bessel +towgs84=-384,664,-48,0,0,0,0 +no_defs +type=crs");

var crs = new L.Proj.CRS('EPSG:4219',
proj4.defs('EPSG:4219'),
{
    origin: [0, 0],
    resolutions: [
        4096, 2048, 1024, 512, 256, 128, 64, 32, 16
    ],
    bounds: L.bounds([105.07, -3.3], [108.35, -1.44])
});

let map = L.map('map', {
    crs: crs,
    zoom: 2,
    minZoom: 2,
    maxZoom: 10,
    maxBoundsViscosity: 1.0,
    worldCopyJump: true,
    attributionControl:false,
    zoomControl: false,
    almostSamplingPeriod: 10,
    almostDistance: 25,
});


See the last comment to your question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/484648/switching-the-coordinate-system-dynamically-in-leaflet

I understand that. But if I want to set the coordinate system initially, I get an error. To give you an example:
`proj4.defs("EPSG:4219","+proj=longlat +ellps=bessel +towgs84=-384,664,-48,0,0,0,0 +no_defs +type=crs");
var crs = new L.Proj.CRS('EPSG:4219',
proj4.defs('EPSG:4219'),
{
origin: [0, 0],
resolutions: [
4096, 2048, 1024, 512, 256, 128, 64, 32, 16
],
bounds: L.bounds([105.07, -3.3], [108.35, -1.44])
});`
https://epsg.io/4219
I get same error

I added my code above in the question, check it out

Did you manage to display map with your desired projection without fancy CRS changing code, just setting it as initial projection? Here is simple working JSFiddle of changing map CRS: https://jsfiddle.net/TomazicM/9a5t6rk8/
